# CSS Navigation with Secondary Nav issues

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fix this navigation menu I'm having issues with:

It is a 2 level menu but it is making the first link with the secondary menu pushes the rest of the main menu under it.

```css
// Navigation
.nav {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;

    .nav-item {
        float: left;
        display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
        a {
            display: block;
            padding: 15px 20px;
            color: #FFF;
            background: #34495E;
            &:hover {
                background: #2C3E50;
            }
        }
        ul {
            li {
                float: left;
                display: inline;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<header>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="four columns">
                        <a href="#" class="logo" title="Site (home)">Site</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="eight columns">
                        <a id="nav-toggle" class="mobile-menu" href="#"><span></span> Menu</a>
                        <nav class="nav">
                            <ul class="nav-list">
                                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" title="Link 1">Link 1</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#" title="Link 1">Link 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" title="Link 2">Link 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" title="Link 3">Link 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" title="Link 4">Link 4</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" title="Link 5">Link 5</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" title="Link 6">Link 6</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" title="Link 7">Link 7</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" title="Link 8">Link 8</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" title="Link 2">Link 2</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" title="Awkward Long link">Awkward Long link</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" title="Link 3">Link 3</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" title="Link 4">Link 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </header>
```

Comment: Could you give some more details on how you'd expect it to look? Right now it's difficult to know what you're aiming for.

Comment: So main menu always at the top like link 1 | link 2 | link 3 | link 4 and the secondary menu will always sit under the main menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `display:inline`s, make your `nav-item` `position:relative` and then make your second level ul `position:absolute; top:100%;` (you may also need to add a width to this):

```css
// Navigation
.nav {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
.nav .nav-item {
  float: left;
  position:relative;
}
.nav .nav-item a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #34495E;
}
.nav .nav-item a:hover {
  background: #2C3E50;
}
.nav .nav-item ul {
  position:absolute; 
  top:100%;
}
.nav .nav-item ul li {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="four columns">
        <a href="#" class="logo" title="Site (home)">Site</a>
      </div>
      <div class="eight columns">
        <a id="nav-toggle" class="mobile-menu" href="#"><span></span> Menu</a>
        <nav class="nav">
          <ul class="nav-list">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" title="Link 1">Link 1</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="Link 1">Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Link 2">Link 2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Link 3">Link 3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Link 4">Link 4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Link 5">Link 5</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Link 6">Link 6</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Link 7">Link 7</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Link 8">Link 8</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" title="Link 2">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" title="Awkward Long link">Awkward Long link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" title="Link 3">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" title="Link 4">Link 4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: Created a fiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/0cb5d1uw/ Only change is that I added the hover functionality, as I presume that's what the original poster wanted (though I may be wrong).

Comment: Thanks mate, what would i change to make the secondary menu inline from than a list? thanks again dude - wont be a hover state :)

Comment: @Donuttt, wasn't sure if they had hover functionality through js, I just thought they didn't want the second level ul to cause the first level lis to be pushed down to the second line

Comment: Sorry should of said, it will literally have the root level left to right and the secondary left to right but always under the root level menu :)

Comment: @James, if you want them all on the same line then you would need to add a width to the ul.  Now if you want them to start from the beginning of the line all the time and not under the the li it is in then change the position relative from the li to the parent ul: https://jsfiddle.net/0cb5d1uw/3

Comment: Weird, i added the width but did not seem to work on the SCSS verison. ill keep playing lol thanks for your help though mate.

Comment: 100% width did not do the trick but it i set a fixed width works but of course i need to be auto... any ideas if im missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I went home ill yesterday.  Instead of setting a width try setting `left:0; right:0;`  NNot sure why 100% doesn't work but 1000 does.  Seems a bit strange!